# Splicing g. 655 with g. 652?

Tags: layer1, fiber, cabling, optical

I have question regarding what type of cable shall I use in this situation to minimize the loss as much as possible.

- We have an old G.655 cable that is being used in the 1310 Wavelength and we want to lay a new fiber cable and patch it to the old one using patch panel. So, Since the G.652 is better in the 1310 Wavelength and the old cable is G.655, Shall we use a G.652 or a G.655 in this case ?

Best Regards

Comment: First - get working solution. Summary dispersion in proposed link must be acceptable to wirk on planned waveleght.

Next is thin optimization. Depends on "How You can use this cables in future"

Answer (score 2):

Stay on G655, and if you want to minimize the loss, switch the optics to 1550nm (You can use 1 DWDM frequency without splitter)...

This is a good solution to make your fiber ready for a DWDM upgrade.

Having a mixed 655/652 fiber is not a good idea, you will never know the exact dispersion of your fiber.